# Lie Symmetry Third Prolongation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lie-groups

I am working on solving a PDE using Lie Symmetries.
The equation I have to solve is third order, and as such I need to find the third prolongation, $\eta^{xxx}$

I cannot find the explicit form of this prolongation, so I have had to determine $\eta^{xxx}$ myself.

I'd like to know if I have the correct expansion.

Here is what I have:

\begin{equation} \label{eq:n_x}
    \begin{split}
     \eta^{x} & = D_x \eta - u_x D_x \xi - u_t D_x \tau \\
    & = \eta_x +  \eta_u u_x -  \xi_x u_x - \xi_u u^2_x -  \tau_x u_t -  \tau_u u_t u_x \\
    & = \eta_x + (\eta_u - \xi_x) u_x -  \xi_u u^2_x -  \tau_x u_t -  \tau_u u_t u_x \\   
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \label{eq: n_xx}
     \begin{split}
\eta^{xx} & = D_x (\eta^{x}) - u_{xx} D_x \xi - u_{xt} D_x \tau \\
& = \eta_{xx} + \eta_{xu} u_{x} + \eta_{xu} u_x +  \eta_{uu} u^2_x + \eta_u u_{xx} \\
& - \xi_{xx} u_x  - \xi_{xu }u^2_x - \xi_x u_{xx} - \xi_{xu} u^2_{x} - \xi_{uu} u^3_x - 2\xi_u u_x u_{xx} \\
& -\tau_{xx} u_t - \tau_{xu} u_x u_t - \tau_x u_{xt} - \tau_{xu}u_tu_x - \tau_{uu}u^2_xu_t - \tau_uu_tu_{xx} - \tau_uu_xu_{xt} \\
& - \xi_x u_{xx} - \xi_u u_x u_{xx} - \tau_x u_{xt} - \tau_u u_x u_{xt} \\
& = \eta_{xx} + (2 \eta_{xu} - \xi_{xx})u_x - \tau_{xx}u_t + (\eta_{uu} - 2\xi_{xu}) u^2_x - \xi_{uu}u^3_x - 2\tau_{xu}u_xu_t \\
& + (\eta_u - 2\xi_x)u_{xx} - 2\tau_x u_{xt} - 3\xi_u u_x u_{xx} - \tau_u u_t u_{xx} - 2\tau_u u_x u_{xt} 
     \end{split}
 \end{equation}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:n_xxx}
     \begin{split}
         \eta^{xxx} & = D_x (\eta^{xx}) - u_{xxx} D_x \xi - u_{xxt} D_x \tau \\
         & = \eta_{xxx} + (3 \eta_{xxu} - \xi_{xxx})u_x + (3\eta_{xuu} - 3\xi_{xxu})u^2_x + (\eta_{uuu} - 3\xi_{xuu})u^3_x - \xi_{uuu}u^4_x \\
         &  - \tau_{xxx} u_t - 3\tau_{xxu}u_xu_t - 3\tau_{xuu}u^2_xu_t - \tau_{uuu}u^3_xu_t  - 3\tau_{xx}u_{xt} + (3\eta_{xu} - 3\xi_{xx})u_{xx} \\
         &   + (3\eta_{uu} - 9\xi_{xu})u_x u_{xx} - 6\xi_{uu}u^2_x u_{xx} - 6\tau_{xu}u_xu_{xt} - 3\tau_{uu}u^2_x u_{xt} -3\tau_{xu}u_t u_{xx} - 3\xi_u u^2_{xx} \\
         &  - 3\tau_u u_{xt}u_{xx} - 3\tau_{uu}u_x u_t u_{xx} + (\eta_u - 3\xi_x) u_{xxx} -4\xi_u u_x u_{xxx} - 3\tau_x u_{xxt} - 3\tau_u u_x u_{xxt} - \tau_u u_t u_{xxx}
     \end{split}
 \end{equation}

I know the first and second prolongations are correct.

Is the third prolongation also correct?

Thanks